# How To Encrypt/Decrypt MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB Cloud to store my data. I want to now add encryption/decryption of data and want to know how to implement it?

I believe I should not be able to see field data from MongoDB compass. My questions are:

1. Do we need to implement encryption/decryption to cloud DB?
2. Are there any built-in ways I configure encryption/decryption from
   MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: You have to decide whether you need data encrypted when you store it in cloud. Have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/ The other option, [Encryption at Rest](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/) encrypts the entire data files, thus an admin of your MongoDB cloud provider would have access to your data.